# How to implement parsec's try method?

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads

I want to implement the same method as parsec's [try](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:try) method. But instead of using a parse transformer, I am using a `Parser` object that holds state:

```
try :: Parser String -> Parser String
try p = P $ \s -> case doParse p s of
            [] -> [("", s)]
            [(a, s')] -> [(a, s')]
```

I'm pretty sure my effort is way off the mark here. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
newtype Parser a = P (String -> [(a, String)])

instance Functor Parser where
   fmap = liftA

instance Applicative Parser where
   pure x    = P (\cs -> [ (x,cs) ])
   p1 <*> p2 = P (\cs -> do (f, cs')  <- doParse p1 cs
                            (x, cs'') <- doParse p2 cs'
                            return (f x, cs''))

instance Monad Parser where
    return = pure
    p1 >>= f = P (\cs -> let [(a, s)] = doParse p1 cs
                         in doParse (f a) s)

instance Alternative Parser where
  -- the parser that always fails
  empty     = P $ const []
  -- | Combine two parsers together in parallel, but only use the
  -- first result. This means that the second parser is used only
  -- if the first parser completely fails.
  p1 <|> p2 = P $ \cs -> case doParse (p1 `choose` p2) cs of
                          []   -> []
                          x:_ -> [x]

doParse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
doParse (P p) = p
```

EDIT:

Example of what I would like to parse:

```
<!-- This is a random 
     HTML
   Comment -->
```

By running:

```
doParse simpleComment excomment
```

simpleComment is taken from the Parsec website, along with manyTill:

```
simpleComment   = do{ string "<!--"
                     ; manyTill anyChar (try (string "-->"))
                     }

manyTill p end      = scan
                    where
                      scan  = do{ _ <- end; return [] }
                            <|>
                              do{ x <- p; xs <- scan; return (x:xs) }
```

Comment: Why do you think you need an equivalent of `try`?

Comment: I'm parsing HTML and need it for lookahead functions

Comment: Your `(>>=)` method looks suspect. What if `doParse p1 cs` returns more than one result -- or none, for that matter?

Comment: Yes at the moment it only returns the first result..

Comment: I would start with a test here.  Show (yourself first of all) what you need to parse and how your current combinators fall short. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `try` for your kind of parser.  Or, if you really want one, you can define it trivially as:

```
try :: Parser a -> Parser a
try = id
```

Parsec makes a distinction between failing after consuming some input and failing without consuming any input.  For example, if you look at the documentation for Parsec's [`(<|>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:-60--124--62-), you'll find an important emphasized piece of text:

> The parser `p <|> q` first applies `p`. If it succeeds, the value of `p` is returned. If `p` fails ***without consuming any input,*** parser `q` is tried.

Unstated is the fact that, if `p` fails after consuming partial input, the whole thing fails and `q` is never tried.  That means that in Parsec, the parser:

```
broken :: Parser String
broken = string "hello" <|> string "hi"
```

doesn't work.  It can parse `"hello"`, but it can't parse `"hi"`, because the first parser `string "hello"` consumes the `"h"` before discovering that the rest doesn't match, so it never tries the `string "hi"` parser:

```
> parseTest broken "hello"
"hello"
> parseTest broken "hi"
parse error at (line 1, column 1):
unexpected "i"
expecting "hello"
```

To fix this, you have to use `try`, which allows you to override this rule:

```
okay :: Parser String
okay = try (string "hello") <|> string "hi"
```

giving:

```
> parseTest okay "hello"
"hello"
> parseTest okay "hi"
"hi"
```

Your parser is different.  Even though you haven't given a definition of `choose`, I can tell from your `Parser` type that it has no sensible way of signalling "failure after consuming input" versus "failure without consuming input", so your implementation of `p <|> q` undoubtedly tries `q` whenever `p` fails, even if it fails after processing a bit of input.

As a result, your parser acts as if every single term is surrounded by `try`, so a `try` function would be redundant.